# Check the render method of `App`. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error even after playing around with the imports statements?
Full error message:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`. Error: Element type is invalid:
> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
> composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
> your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
> up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
> at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:30611:21)
> at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:30632:19)
> at createChild (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:19201:32)
> at reconcileChildrenArray (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:19441:29)
> at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:19783:20)
> at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:22715:32)
> at updateHostComponent (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:23359:7)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:24804:18)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:9790:18)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:8787/static/js/bundle.js:9834:20)

My App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import OrganizationChart from './OrganizationChart';
import {OrgChart} from 'react-orgchart'; 
import 'react-orgchart/index.css';

function App() {
    const initechOrg = {
        name: "Bill Lumbergh",
        actor: "Gary Cole",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Peter Gibbons",
            actor: "Ron Livingston",
            children: [
              {
                name: "And More!!",
                actor: "This is just to show how to build a complex tree with multiple levels of children. Enjoy!"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Milton Waddams",
            actor: "Stephen Root"
          },
          {
            name: "Bob Slydell",
            actor: "John C. McGi..."
          },
        ]
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1>The Organization Chart</h1>
                <OrgChart tree={initechOrg} OrganizationChart={OrganizationChart} />
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App ;
```

and my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And as aforementioned, I've tried both `export default App ;` ... `import App from './App';` and `export {app}` and `import {App} from './App';` in App.js and Index.js respectively, and I'm still getting the same exact as error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's:

```
import OrgChart from 'react-orgchart';
```

not:

```
import {OrgChart} from 'react-orgchart';
```

checkout the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-orgchart)